Rust Unable to Bind Parameters in SQLx for Non-Standard Queries (e.g., CREATE VIEW) in Rust
I'm facing an issue with SQLx in Rust where parameter binding fails when attempting to execute queries beyond the standard ones like SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE.
// This query works fine with parameter binding
let result = sqlx::query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column = $1")
.bind("123")
.fetch_all(&conn)
.await?;

// This doesn't
let result = sqlx::query("CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column = $1")
.bind("123")
.execute(&conn)
.await?;

It doesn't raise any error, and it permits me to bind the parameter. However, PostgreSQL doesn't receive it, resulting in the following error:
there is no parameter $1
Is there another method to accomplish this, without resorting to injecting parameters directly into the query string? I'm concerned about potential security risks associated with that.

I believe sqlx does not support parameters for non-DML statements. You also should use raw_sql() (although it should error if not).

Postgres doesn't support parameters for DML commands. Unfortunately, CREATE VIEW AS SELECT is DML command. Usual DML commands - CREATE, DROP, ALTER has not execution plan, and then the execution is different.
